# Error Restoring Model in Tensorflow After Changing the Optimizer Paramter

Tags: optimization, tensorflow

I have trained a model in Tensorflow. During the training process, I was setting a var_list in the optimizer, in other words, I was training a GRU on top of a CNN. Here is the code for the optimizer:

```
with tf.name_scope('optimizer'):
    update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
    with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.0001).minimize(MSE, var_list=gru_output_var_list)
```

Then, after training, and saving the variables in checkpoints, I was trying to remove the `var_list` from the optimizer in order to be able to fine tune the whole network, conv layers with GRU. But, that is raising an error:

```
Key weight_fc_sig/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
```

where `weight_fc_sig` is the name of one of the variables in the model.

I have read through github, and I found that the state of the optimizer is saved as well as variables in the checkpoint. So, I would like to know how to solve this issue, in other words, I need to know how to reset the state of the optimizer.

Any help is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To begin with, I build a model in tensorflow, and then I saved the graph, with variables... into a checkpoint through:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
saver.save(sess, model_path + "ckpt")
```

So when I inspect the list of variables stored through:

```
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
model_path = 'C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/TensorflowDifferentProjects/MNIStDataset/tensorlogs/ckpt'
reader = pywrap_tensorflow.NewCheckpointReader(model_path)
var_to_shape_map = reader.get_variable_to_shape_map()

for key in sorted(var_to_shape_map):
    print("tensor_name: ", key)
```

I got the following list of variables:

```
tensor_name:  Adam_optimizer/beta1_power
tensor_name:  Adam_optimizer/beta2_power
tensor_name:  conv1/biases
tensor_name:  conv1/biases/Adam
tensor_name:  conv1/biases/Adam_1
tensor_name:  conv1/weights
tensor_name:  conv1/weights/Adam
tensor_name:  conv1/weights/Adam_1
tensor_name:  conv2/biases
tensor_name:  conv2/biases/Adam
tensor_name:  conv2/biases/Adam_1
tensor_name:  conv2/weights
tensor_name:  conv2/weights/Adam
tensor_name:  conv2/weights/Adam_1
tensor_name:  fc1/biases
tensor_name:  fc1/biases/Adam
tensor_name:  fc1/biases/Adam_1
tensor_name:  fc1/weights
tensor_name:  fc1/weights/Adam
tensor_name:  fc1/weights/Adam_1
tensor_name:  fc2/biases
tensor_name:  fc2/biases/Adam
tensor_name:  fc2/biases/Adam_1
tensor_name:  fc2/weights
tensor_name:  fc2/weights/Adam
tensor_name:  fc2/weights/Adam_1
```

And when I trained the same model another time, but this time, I passed to the saver only the list of the weights and biases as:
saver = tf.train.Saver(var_list=lst_vars), and then I printed out the list of weights and biases saved,
I got the following list:

```
tensor_name:  conv1/biases
tensor_name:  conv1/weights
tensor_name:  conv2/biases
tensor_name:  conv2/weights
tensor_name:  fc1/biases
tensor_name:  fc1/weights
tensor_name:  fc2/biases
tensor_name:  fc2/weights
```

Now, when I tried to run the same model again, but with removing the list of variables to restore, So I have this saver now:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver(),
```

I ran into the following error:

```
Key fc2/weights/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint.
```

Therefore, the solution was to mention explicitly the list of variables I need to restore. In other words, even when I only
saved the list of weights and biases I need to store, when importing them, I should mention them specifically, so I should
say:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver(var_list=lst_vars)
```

where `lst_vars` is the list of variables I need to restore which is the same as the one
printed above.

***So in general what happens is that whenever we try to restore the graph, if I didnt mention the list of variables to restore,
tensorflow will look and see that there are some variables that are not stored yet, I other words, whenever there is no list,
tensorflow assumes that we are trying to restore the whole graph, which is not true. I am only restoring the part responsible
for weights and biases. So once this is mentioned, tensorflow will know that I am not initializing the whole graph, but part
of it.***

Now even if I was truly mentioning the list of variables I need to restore, as follows:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver(var_list=lst_vars)
```

This will not cause any problem

### Also, I can add/modify the var_list passed to the optimizer, that will not cause any problem as well.

At the same time, even if I passed the list of variables for the optimizer to work on as:

```
with tf.name_scope('Adam_optimizer'):
    train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy, var_list=lst_vars[:3])

saver = tf.train.Saver(var_list=lst_vars)
```

Then I can run the same model another time but without the var_list parameter in the optimizer. So that would be the case with fine tuning.

---

Now, to go the extra mile, I can modify the model, add maybe more layers, but I should keep in mind, since I have only the
following variables stored in the checkpoint:

```
tensor_name:  conv1/biases
tensor_name:  conv1/weights
tensor_name:  conv2/biases
tensor_name:  conv2/weights
tensor_name:  fc1/biases
tensor_name:  fc1/weights
tensor_name:  fc2/biases
tensor_name:  fc2/weights
```

I should mention to the saver that these are the variables that I am restoring. So I said the following:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver(var_list=[lst_vars[0], lst_vars[1], lst_vars[2], lst_vars[3],
                             lst_vars[6], lst_vars[7], lst_vars[8], lst_vars[9]])
```

In this case, there would be no problem and the code will run fine!!!
and I can ask the optimizer as well to train the new model, maybe train certain parameters, I mean weights and biases and so on...

Also, note that I can save the whole model as:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
```

and then restore part of the model (by running the model another time, and pass:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver(var_list=lst_vars))
```

Also, I can modify the model and maybe add more conv layer. So I can fine tune the model as long as I mention exactly what
variables I am restoring. Ex:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver(var_list=[lst_vars[0], lst_vars[1], lst_vars[2], lst_vars[3],
                             lst_vars[6], lst_vars[7], lst_vars[8], lst_vars[9]])
```

**all this explanation came because I though there might some problems with the optimizer, and I needed to know how to rest it. An issue was raised on github, exactly on how to rest the optimizer, and that it why I came up with all this conclusion**

---

Here is the code for whomever is interested:

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
import tensorflow as tf
import os


def conv2d(x, w):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x, w, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')


def max_pool_2x2(x):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')


def weight_variable(shape, name):
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(initial, name=name)


def bias_variable(shape, name):
    initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
    return tf.Variable(initial, name=name)


def deepnn(x):
    with tf.name_scope('reshape'):
        x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 28, 28, 1])

    # First convolutional layer, maps one grayscale image to 32 feature maps.
    with tf.name_scope('conv1'):
        w_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 1, 32], name='weights')
        b_conv1 = bias_variable([32], name='biases')
        h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, w_conv1) + b_conv1)

    # Pooling layer, downsampling by 2X
    with tf.name_scope('pool1'):
        h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)

    # Second convolutional layer -- maps 32 feature maps to 64
    with tf.name_scope('conv2'):
        w_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 32, 64], name='weights')
        b_conv2 = bias_variable([64], name='biases')
        h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, w_conv2) + b_conv2)

    # Second pooling layer
    with tf.name_scope('pool2'):
        h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)

    # Fully connected layer 1 -- after 2 round of downsampling, our 28 x 28 image is
    # down to 7 x 7 x 64 feature maps -- maps this to 1024 features.
    with tf.name_scope('fc1'):
        w_fc1 = weight_variable([7 * 7 * 64, 1024], name='weights')
        b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024], name='biases')

        h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 7 * 7 * 64])
        h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, w_fc1) + b_fc1)

    # Dropout - control the complexity of the model, prevents co-adaptation of features
    with tf.name_scope('dropout'):
        keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
        h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)

    # Map the 1024 features to 10 classes, one for each digit.
    with tf.name_scope('fc2'):
        w_fc2 = weight_variable([1024, 10], name='weights')
        b_fc2 = bias_variable([10], name='biases')

        y_conv = tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, w_fc2) + b_fc2

    return y_conv, keep_prob


mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True)

# Create the model
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])

# Define loss and optimizer
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])

# Build the graph for the deep net
y_conv, keep_prob = deepnn(x)

with tf.name_scope('loss'):
    cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y_conv)

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)

# Note that this list of variables only include the weights and biases in the model.
lst_vars = []
for v in tf.global_variables():
    lst_vars.append(v)
    print(v.name, '....')

with tf.name_scope('Adam_optimizer'):
    train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)

with tf.name_scope('accuracy'):
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.arg_max(y_conv, 1), tf.arg_max(y_, 1))
    correct_prediction = tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32)

accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(correct_prediction)

model_path = 'C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/TensorflowDifferentProjects/MNIStDataset/tensorlogs/'

saver = tf.train.Saver(var_list=lst_vars)

train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(model_path + "EventsFile/")
train_writer.add_graph(tf.get_default_graph())

for v in tf.global_variables():
    print(v.name)

# Note that a session is created within a with block so that it is destroyed
# once the block has been exited.
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print('all variables initialized!!')

    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(
        os.path.dirname(model_path))
    if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
        saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
        print('checkpoints are saved!!!')
    else:
        print('No stored checkpoints')

    for i in range(700):
        batch = mnist.train.next_batch(50)
        if i % 100 == 0:
            train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0})
            print('step %d, training accuracy %g' % (i, train_accuracy))

        train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 0.5})

    print('test accuracy %g' % accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
        x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels, keep_prob: 1.0}))

    save_path = saver.save(sess, model_path + "ckpt")
```

### And the modified model (Where I added another convlolutional layer):

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
import tensorflow as tf
import os

def conv2d(x, w):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x, w, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

def max_pool_2x2(x):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')

def weight_variable(shape, name):
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(initial, name=name)

def bias_variable(shape, name):
    initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
    return tf.Variable(initial, name=name)

def deepnn(x):

    with tf.name_scope('reshape'):
        x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 28, 28, 1])

    # First convolutional layer, maps one grayscale image to 32 feature maps.
    with tf.name_scope('conv1'):
        w_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 1, 32], name='weights')
        b_conv1 = bias_variable([32], name='biases')
        h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, w_conv1) + b_conv1)

    # Pooling layer, downsampling by 2X
    with tf.name_scope('pool1'):
        h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)

    # Second convolutional layer -- maps 32 feature maps to 64
    with tf.name_scope('conv2'):
        w_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 32, 64], name='weights')
        b_conv2 = bias_variable([64], name='biases')
        h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, w_conv2) + b_conv2)

    # Second pooling layer
    with tf.name_scope('pool2'):
        h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)

    with tf.name_scope('conv3'):
        w_conv3 = weight_variable([1, 1, 64, 64], name='weights')
        b_conv3 = bias_variable([64], name='biases')
        h_conv3 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool2, w_conv3) + b_conv3)

    # Fully connected layer 1 -- after 2 round of downsampling, our 28 x 28 image is
    # down to 7 x 7 x 64 feature maps -- maps this to 1024 features.
    with tf.name_scope('fc1'):
        w_fc1 = weight_variable([7 * 7 * 64, 1024], name='weights')
        b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024], name='biases')

        h_conv3_flat = tf.reshape(h_conv3, [-1, 7 * 7 * 64])
        h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_conv3_flat, w_fc1) + b_fc1)

    # Dropout - control the complexity of the model, prevents co-adaptation of features
    with tf.name_scope('dropout'):
        keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
        h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)

    # Map the 1024 features to 10 classes, one for each digit.
    with tf.name_scope('fc2'):
        w_fc2 = weight_variable([1024, 10], name='weights')
        b_fc2 = bias_variable([10], name='biases')

        y_conv = tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, w_fc2) + b_fc2

    return y_conv, keep_prob

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True)

# Create the model
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])

# Define loss and optimizer
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])

# Build the graph for the deep net
y_conv, keep_prob = deepnn(x)

with tf.name_scope('loss'):
    cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y_conv)

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)

# Note that this list of variables only include the weights and biases in the model.
lst_vars = []
for v in tf.global_variables():
    lst_vars.append(v)
    print(v.name, '....')

with tf.name_scope('Adam_optimizer'):
    train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)

with tf.name_scope('accuracy'):
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.arg_max(y_conv, 1), tf.arg_max(y_, 1))
    correct_prediction = tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32)

accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(correct_prediction)

model_path = 'C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/TensorflowDifferentProjects/MNIStDataset/tensorlogs/'

saver = tf.train.Saver(var_list=[lst_vars[0], lst_vars[1], lst_vars[2], lst_vars[3],
                                 lst_vars[6], lst_vars[7], lst_vars[8], lst_vars[9]])

train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(model_path + "EventsFile/")
train_writer.add_graph(tf.get_default_graph())

for v in tf.global_variables():
    print(v.name)

# Note that a session is created within a with block so that it is destroyed
# once the block has been exited.
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    print('all variables initialized!!')

    ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(
        os.path.dirname(model_path))
    if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
        saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
        print('checkpoints are saved!!!')
    else:
        print('No stored checkpoints')

    for i in range(700):
        batch = mnist.train.next_batch(50)
        if i % 100 == 0:
            train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0})
            print('step %d, training accuracy %g' % (i, train_accuracy))

        train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 0.5})

    print('test accuracy %g' % accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
        x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels, keep_prob: 1.0}))

    save_path = saver.save(sess, model_path + "ckpt")
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Do you know why tensorflow is looking for the variable `fc2/weights/Adam_1` even if it is not part of the stored model?

Comment: @MartinR. Adam optimizer will create some variables to be used for training other variables that "YOU" created in the model. Therefore, we don't touch the variables created by adam optimizer. Hope this answers your question?